# How to use Docker Hub private repos at GKE?

Tags: containers, dockerhub, google-kubernetes-engine

I am migrating a huge cloud cluster from AWS to GKE.
But I am having trouble authenticating with Docker Hub, I keep getting 
`Failed to pull image "myorg/mycontainer": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: repository myorg/mycontainer not found: does not exist or no pull access`

It seems that the way to authenticate gcloud with docker has recently changed, so whats the proper way of tdoint this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Kubernetes accessing private Docker Hub hosted images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826766/google-cloud-kubernetes-accessing-private-docker-hub-hosted-images)

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Learn about imagePullSecrets https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass your docker hub login credentials as a secret

`kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL`

where --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/

Now, you can create pods which reference that secret by adding an imagePullSecrets section to a pod definition.

````
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: awesomeapps
spec:
  containers:
    - name: foo
      image: janedoe/awesomeapp:v1
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey```
````